# Spring Boot not loading static resources it depends on RequestMapping depth

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping, static-resource

I have problem to load the file under static folder on spring boot application.

The problem is RequestMapping depth more than 2 like `@RequestMapping("spring/xyz")`

The `@RequestMapping("spring")` single depth works well but 2 depth is prefixed 'spring' it is connect localhost:8080/spring/'static folder'

I found half solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997358/spring-boot-request-mapping-not-loading-static-resources)

my folder structure is:

```
static/css/some.css  
static/templates/velocity.vm
```

case 1: works well

```
java:
    @RequestMapping("spring")

html:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/some.css">
```

case2: works well

```
java:
    @RequestMapping("spring/xyz")

html:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/some.css">
```

***case3: not working***

```
java:
    @RequestMapping("spring/xyz/123")

html:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/some.css">
```

it is called `'http//localhost/spring/xyz/css/some.css'`

case3: works well

```
java:
    @RequestMapping("spring/xyz/123")

html:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/some.css">
```

case4: works well

```
java:
    @RequestMapping("123")

html:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/some.css">
```

It works!! even if I use `../../` relative path.
I don't know why this works.

Actually I didn't understand Spring Boot API well that I consider use ViewResoler something load other static resources.

I want to know this load path machanism and how to the RequestMapping url path link to call the 'http//localhost/spring/xyz/css/some.css'

I appriciate any answer thanks~!!

I refer to the same issue on spring.io [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) from 'metalhead' and 'Brian Clozel'

Comment: Just use slash at the beginning of the address: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/spring/xyz/css/some.css">`

Comment: wow it works well. I want know how to work this behind. can you give some spring doc or explain it? Thanks @NickSavenia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39545949/6066470

Comment: @NickSavenia really helpful !!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using thymeleaf you can also specify the path as :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"
href="../static/css/main.css" />
```

it worked properly for me for any depth.